# Proxy tunneling failed: ForbiddenUnable to establish SSL connection

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, proxy

Trying to install the python on the Ubuntu box and encountered following issues

> root@abc:~# wget --server-response -v
>   https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/Python-2.7.16.tgz
>   --2019-08-14 13:22:55--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/Python-2.7.16.tgz Connecting
>   to 10.221.196.30:8080... connected. Proxy tunneling failed:
>   ForbiddenUnable to establish SSL connection.

environment details :

```
root@abc:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

root@abc:~# python --version
Python 2.7.12
root@abc:~#
```

i verified that proxy has been configured properly in the `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc` files

```
root@abc:~# echo $http_proxy
http://10.221.196.30:8080
root@abc:~# echo $https_proxy
http://10.221.196.30:8080
```

to validate that , i executed git clone command and it worked

```
root@abc:~# git clone https://github.com/abc/kubernetes-config.git
Cloning into 'kubernetes-config'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 115, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (99/99), done.
remote: Total 115 (delta 75), reused 39 (delta 14), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (115/115), 13.42 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (75/75), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
root@abc:~#
```

i m not getting what is missing . please suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue. it was due to the few URLs which are not white listed in the proxy server configuration.

after white-listing , error vanished.

Comment: In my case as well, this was the same issue. Resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here and tried a couple of things, like connecting from a different server ( it worked ), and connecting from my computer ( it worked ), but from some servers or computers, I was getting the same error. So I commented this line in the squid configuration file: /etc/squid/squid.conf

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```